# cannot delete directory using shell command

Tags: linux, shell

I wanted to delete all directories with name in same pattern `RC_200`, here is what I did:

```
find -name "RC_200" -type d -delete
```

But it's complaining about this:

```
find: cannot delete '.RC200': Directory not empty
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try:

`find . -name RC200 -type d -exec rm -r {} \;`

You can see [here](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20.%20-name%20RC200%20-type%20d%20-exec%20rm%20-r%20%7B%7D%20%5C%3B), what the command does

More, you can try what @anubhava recommended in comment (Note the `+` at the end); this one is equivalent to a `xargs` solution:

`find . -name RC200 -type d -print0|xargs -0 rm -r`

`xargs` executes the command passed as parameter, with the arguments passed to `stdin`. This is using `rm -r` to delete the directory and all its children

Comment: Great idea to document your solution with explainshell.

Comment: As optimization I would recommend the usage of `parallel` instead of `xargs`: `find . -print0 | parallel -0 -I "{}" rm -rf "{}"`

Comment: @DanieleOrlando, `xargs` deals badly with special characters (such as `space`, `\`, `'` and `"`) which the OP didn't mention, so I think it's ok ^^ In most of the cases `xargs` offers some of the same possibilities as GNU `parallel`

Answer (score -1):

May be you should run administrator privilege.

if your os Ubuntu add "sudo" before your Command or what ever your os look at administrator key.

OR

remove file protection if it has.

Comment: The error is "Directory not empty", not "Permission denied" as would be expected if it were a permissions problem.